# App store rejected my app due to "Cannot contact reCAPTCHA. Check your connection and try again"

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication, app-store, recaptcha

App is built in flutter using Firebase authentication. When Apple review team tries to sign in by using provided testing phone number and they always stuck at reCaptcha based authentication screen. They are seeing attached screen forever.

**App store rejected by giving reason:**

> Hello,
>
> The issues we previously identified still need your attention.
>
> If you have any questions, we are here to help. Reply to this message
> in App Store Connect and let us know.
>
> Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness
>
> We discovered one or more bugs in your app.
>
> Specifically, your app still displayed error message when we tried to
> login.
>
> Please review the details below and complete the next steps.
>
> Review device details:
>
> - Device type: iPhone
> - OS version: iOS 15.5
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please run your app on a device to reproduce the issues, then revise
> and submit your app for review. If at first you're unable to reproduce
> the issue, try the following:
>
> - For new apps, uninstall all previous versions of your app from a device, then install and follow the steps to reproduce.
> - For app updates, install the new version as an update to the previous version, then follow the steps to reproduce.
>
> If we misunderstood the intended behavior of your app, please reply to
> this message in App Store Connect to provide information on how these
> features were intended to work.
>
> Resources
>
> - For information about testing apps and preparing them for review, see Technical Note TN2431: App Testing Guide.
> - To learn about troubleshooting networking issues, see About Networking.
>
> Please see attached screenshot for details.

[Issue faced by Apple Review Team](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qx0k.png)

**I have tried following things:**

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth#set-up-recaptcha-verification - As per this link i have done same configuration in Xcode, Put my REVERSED_CLIENT_ID in the URL schemes,

[iOS URL Scheme in xCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afhUg.png)

Also I have done APNs authentication key at firebase side,
[Firebase APNS Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ir2cI.png)

However, I am unable to reproduce this issue at my end. But though, I tried all the possible solution based on answers on the SO. Still issue doesn't resolved for them.

**Please let me know if am I missing some configuration?**

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

1. Go to your firebase Project settings => App Check => Apps
2. Register your apps for app attention.

Comment: Thanks but already registered!

Comment: any help?

im also stuck on the same problem?